# problems implementing AJAX post

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have a html link, here it is (post php interpretation):

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="vote_comment(28, 1);" class="vote-arrow">
     <img id="up-arrow-pic-comment-28" src="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/backyard-    cures/images/up_arrow_grey.png" alt="vote up" />
</a>
```

Here is the function it is calling:

```
function vote_comment(comment_id, direction) {
    $.post('http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/backyard-cures/backyard_funcs.php',
           {voteType: direction, postId: comment_id, type: 'comment'},
           'updateIcon(vote_count, direction, comment_id)',
           'json');
}
```

Here is the backyard_funcs.php:

```
if (isset($_POST['voteType'], $_POST['postId']) && is_user_logged_in()) {

    if($_POST['type'] == 'comment') {
        if (!get_user_meta(get_current_user_id(),'byc_comment_votes',true)) {
            add_user_meta(get_current_user_id(),'byc_comment_votes',array($_POST['postId'] => $_POST['voteType']),true)
            echo json_encode(array('vote_count' => $_POST['voteType'], 'direction' => $_POST['voteType'], 'comment_id' => $_POST['postId']));
        }
        else {
            echo json_encode(array('vote_count' => $_POST['voteType'], 'direction' => $_POST['voteType'], 'comment_id' => $_POST['postId']));
            //$old_vote=get_user_meta(get_current_user_id(),'byc_comment_votes['.$_POST[postId].']',true);
        }
    }    

} else {
    // bad request/hack attempt
    echo 2;
}
```

I know that the updateIcon function (which is supposed to be called on post success) is not being called. I have been using the chrome debugger. I know execution enters the vote_comment function and from there execution just dies (not sure why). I am not getting any console errors.

I realize this question may be simplistic or unclear. I apologize in advance, I am new to this (web development). Please let me know if any additional info is needed. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you view the network tab, does it show a request being made?  If  so, what is the result?

Comment: You should remove `http://localhost` from the `$.post` url, you are possibly running into cross domain issues.

Comment: In the success function param, you have a string `'updateIcon(vote_count, direction, comment_id)'` rather than a function definition like `function(data){ ... updateIcon(vote_count, direction, comment_id); }`

Comment: lots of comments (which is good). 1) Could you explain how to read the network tab. The results are not so clear.

Comment: @bob, I hope this helps, I'm not sure what you're having trouble with; http://i.imgur.com/vJyWhYw.png

Comment: ok, thanks a lot. That led me to an error in the php.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The third parameter should be a function, not a string.  Here's an example with minimal changes to your code.

```
function vote_comment(comment_id, direction) {
    $.post('http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/backyard-cures/backyard_funcs.php', 
        {voteType: direction, postId: comment_id, type: 'comment'}, 
        function(data) { updateIcon(data.vote_count, data.direction, data.comment_id) },
        'json'
    );
}
```

Edit: added parsing to callback

Edit 2: Turns out the OP was having trouble using chrome debugger, I sent him this image for guidance: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y1uzh.png

After viewing the ajax request response body, he was able to debug the issue on his own which turned out to be in the PHP.

Comment: hey, this didn't help. Same issue as before.

Comment: Did you try watching the network tab as you made the click?  Cause that would really help us help you.

Comment: backyard_funcs.php
/wordpress/wp-content/themes/backyard-cures
POST 200
OK
text/html jquery.min.js:4
Script
660 B
436 B
19 ms
19 ms

Comment: @bob sounds like you found the network response but you should be able to open it, did you see a `+` icon or something? It should contain tabs such as `headers`, `response` and possibly `json` if the server is responding with `json` correctly

Comment: thanks, I figured it out. Its working. Thanks to all.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery [post](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) expects a function is the 3rd parameter.

```
function vote_comment(comment_id, direction) {
    $.post('http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/backyard-cures/backyard_funcs.php',
      {
      voteType: direction,
      postId: comment_id,
      type: 'comment'},
      'updateIcon(vote_count, direction, comment_id)' //the problem is here
      ,'json');
}
```

your code should probably look something like

```
function vote_comment(comment_id, direction) {
    $.post('http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/backyard-cures/backyard_funcs.php',
      {
      voteType: direction,
      postId: comment_id,
      type: 'comment'},
       function(data){
              //data is the server response
              updateIcon(data.vote_count, data.direction, data.comment_id);
       },
       'json');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. However, inasmuch as I understood you, making this change is not helping. What do you mean by data is the server response? Should I have the word "data" in there or something else?

Comment: this answer assumes you have the function `updateIcon` defined in your code ie `function updateIcon(vote_count, direction, comment_id){//do stuff with vote_count, direction, comment_id}` you can use the word `data` or `response` or whatever you like, but you need something to collect the data from the server. Try `console.log(data)` where it says `//data is the server response` then check your console. you'll see what i mean